# One of my integration tests is throwing an exception on an alternate thread which kills MSTest. What is a good pattern to manage this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, mstest

I have a number of integration tests that test my services api's and check responses (http response codes and where applicable the body). The api's themselves are hosted in a webapi service in the azure cloud. My integration tests are a separate project that use my proxy to make restful calls to the webapi and check responses and report back success and failure. The integration tests are subsequently executed using MSTest. Every one of my webapi's use an async await pattern and every one of my proxy calls are async and (as far as I can see) I am await'ing in all cases on my test api calls (indeed, I'm not sure you cannot with MSTest). It seems that on some occasions I receive the dreaded

```
'The agent process was stopped while the test was running.
```

when some failures occur and from what I can tell this is likely to be one of my integration tests failing on *another thread* other than the test-runner (a known problem). As a point of reference, I have created an IDisposable style pattern for my test scenarios:

```
using ( var scenario = new TestScenario() )
{
    // do some testing stuff
}
```

which manages and cleans up downloaded files, manages proxy instances and generally logs information. The question is this: Is there a way to use my existing IDisposable pattern here to try/catch any unhandled exceptions that MSTest seems to not be able to cope with? Or am I stuck with having to wrap every test in a try/catch block of their own and unwrap an AggregateException?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, otherwise I would just comment this...

Anyhow, I'm not entirely familiar with MSTest and if it allows async test execution (e.g. like XUnit does).

Are you awaiting in your tests? If not, are you blocking properly using `var response = obj.ExecuteAsync().Result` or `obj.ExecuteAsync.Wait()`?

If you are blocking properly, then I'd suspect the `using` statement is disposing early. If that's the case, you could implement IDisposable which would execute during teardown and dispose of your managed items there.

Comment: Hey matey, thanks for the response. Yeah. In MSTest you actually can't do async stuff. You *have* to do a .Wait() or a .Result() so in theory this should work. But it doesn't stop you from spinning off threads on the test itself that don't finish after the method.

Comment: @thesenator Task returning test method have been supported for years in mstest. Most of my unit tests are of that format and they work just fine. What doesn't work is starting a thread, not waiting for it to finish and the thread throwing an exception after the original test is finished

Comment: @Voo thank you for that, I've learnt something new. I'd tried recently and had missed the 'async' keyword from the signature which caused the test runner to dislike it (I should have read the error). So you are absolutely right with the signature 'public async Task' rather than my failing 'public Task' signature. It still (as you say) leaves the problem that the test runner can't deal with unfinished threads.

Comment: @thesenator Wow never ran into that. How weird and seemingly unnecessary to introduce such a distinction!